# Using a Chrome Extension content script, how to replace user selected text in a DraftJS editor with some other text

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, draftjs

I am developing a Chrome Extension with a content script that injects a button onto a webpage. The webpage has a DraftJS editor and I need to replace any user-selected text with a string of question marks that matches the length of the selection when the user clicks my extension's button.

I am unable to interact with the React state involved in the process. How can I approach this using Web APIs? I believe this has to do with Selection and Range objects, but I cannot implement a solution myself.

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).